# Can't stay logged in on SEDE

Tags: support, login, data-explorer

I'm having troubles with staying signed in on data.stackexchange.com. I have no issues with any other Stack Exchange site -- they all work fine. Once I log in, I don't need to log in every time I visit the site. But with data.se, I need to re-login everytime. As I can't execute queries without captcha without being logged in, this is an issue.

What could be causing this issue? I'm using Google Chrome 31.0.1650.63, if that matters.